# what is algebraic topology and what its studies

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Could someone provide me with simple terminology what algebraic topology study, what are the tools to study it, and what is the relation with homology. Thank you in advance.

Comment: [This previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1332144/applications-of-algebraic-topology) might help you.

Comment: [This was an answer to a different question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/211731/25554) but it might be helpful for your question.